# How can I merge multiple lines with spaces (blank line) separating them?

Tags: text-processing, scripting, merge

I'd like to merge the following multiple lines of output so that they form a single line:

*line 1:*

> ,,,1,,,,,,,,18,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,42,1,121,1,17,10,21,1,,IU,8,0,,0,
>       ,0,0,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,1227,,,11,,0,,,,1,01,,,1,12769,,7707,0,,,,12769,,,12769,6,0,,,,10,,,1,
>       901,10800,14/04/13,,,4,,,,2,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,A,,,,1001,,,,,,,,,,,01,,12769,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,
>       ,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,14/04/13,10800,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,1,,,,,,,,,964750001210,,1001,,1,,0,,,,,,,,,,,,17
>       ,,,,,,,,,31685125704,,,,1,,1,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,19,0,.901,19,0,.901,,,901,1,,,8767318,13790084045,1,
>       1304150024556817,,,,33399399,,,,,,,,,,,,901,1,,,,,,0,,0,,,,,,GSMT11B*****S***,,,4,,,,,,10800,14/04/1
>       3,10800,14/04/13,443867992,,,,,,,,1,0,,0,,,,,,,61409,51,,,9647507763683,,1001,1,0,,60,0,5,,N,,0,1,I,
>       1,,,,,,47,,,,,54,1,4,19,,29,1,1,1,3,1112,2,,Usage,Usage,USG,,N,N,0,,1,,TRNT01I,90,,0GRI3,90,,,,,0,1,
>       1,1,1,1,34111,437956,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,19,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,H,,1,0,1,0

*...blank line...*

*line 2:*

> ,,,1,,,,,,,,18,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,42,1,121,1,17,10,21,1,,IU,8,0,,0,
>       ,0,0,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,399,,,11,,0,,,,1,01,,,1,61,,67,0,,,,61,,,61,6,0,,,,10,,,1,74,10800,14/
>       04/13,,,4,,,,2,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,A,,,,1001,,,,,,,,,,,01,,61,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
>       14/04/13,10800,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,1,,,,,,,,,964750001210,,1001,,1,,0,,,,,,,,,,,,17,,,,,,,,,9647703
>       026865,,,,1,,1,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,19,0,.061667,19,0,.061667,,,74,1,,,8820807,13790084046,1,130415002
>       4556817,,,,33399399,,,,,,,,,,,,74,1,,,,,,0,,0,,,,,,GSMT11B*****S***,,,4,,,,,,10800,14/04/13,10800,14
>       /04/13,443867993,,,,,,,,1,0,,0,,,,,,,61409,51,,,9647503228592,,1001,1,0,,60,0,5,,N,,0,1,I,1,,,,,,20,
>       ,,,,25,1,4,19,,19,1,1,1,3,980,2,,Usage,Usage,USG,,N,N,0,,1,,ASIA03I,90,,0GRI3,90,,,,,0,1,1,1,1,1,341
>       12,437956,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,19,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,H,,1,0,1,0

*...blank line...*

*line 3:*

> ,,,1,,,,,,,,18,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,42,1,121,1,17,10,21,1,,IU,8,0,,0,
>       ,0,0,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,327,,,11,,0,,,,1,01,,,1,12769,,7707,0,,,,12769,,,12769,6,0,,,,10,,,1,2
>       ,10800,14/04/13,,,4,,,,2,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,A,,,,1001,,,,,,,,,,,01,,12769,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
>       ,,,,,,,,,,,,,14/04/13,10800,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,1,,,,,,,,,964750001210,,1001,,1,,0,,,,,,,,,,,,17,,,
>       ,,,,,,96171254836,,,,1,,1,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,19,0,.002,19,0,.002,,,2,1,,,8825322,13790084047,1,13041
>       50024556817,,,,33399399,,,,,,,,,,,,2,1,,,,,,0,,0,,,,,,GSMT11B*****S***,,,4,,,,,,10800,14/04/13,10800
>       ,14/04/13,443867994,,,,,,,,1,0,,0,,,,,,,61409,51,,,9647501378572,,1001,1,0,,60,0,5,,N,,0,1,I,1,,,,,,
>       47,,,,,54,1,4,19,,29,1,1,1,3,1112,2,,Usage,Usage,USG,,N,N,0,,1,,TRNT01I,90,,0GRI3,90,,,,,0,1,1,1,1,1
>       ,34113,437956,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,19,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,H,,1,0,1,0

*...blank line...*

Comment: Please, give a better explanation of what you want to achieve. What is the input and what is the expected output? Also please use the formatting features of Stackexchange.

Answer (score 4):

If I understand your question correctly you have the following:

```
$ echo -e "line1\nline2\nline3\n"
line1
line2
line3

$
```

And you want this:

```
line1line2line3
```

So you should only need to remove the blank lines. A command like this should do it:

```
$ echo -e "line1\nline2\nline3\n" | paste -s -d ''
line1line2line3
```

I'm not sure where your output is being kept, but if it was in a file you chould use the above to merge the lines:

```
$ paste -s -d '' somefile.txt 
line1line2line3
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach would be to simply remove the new lines from your file:

```
echo $(tr -d '\n' < file) > newfile
```

I am using the `echo` to insert a final new line, if you dont even want that just run

```
tr -d '\n' < file > newfile
```